# XulRunner: hide xul-window taskbar button

Tags: windows, xulrunner

Is there any way to hide taskbar button on xul window opened by window.open or something? In Ms Windows. hidechrome, etc does not do the trick - taskbar buttons are still present for such a windows

If there is no direct way, may be there\a some extensions out there that can be used programatically to archive such goal?

Thank you! Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's `dependent` "feature" string for [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open). It creates a window that's always on top of the owner window and that doesn't show up in sidebar.